# Concatenate text files with Windows command line, dropping leading lines

Tags: windows, command-line, concatenation

I need to concatenate some relatively large text files, and would prefer to do this via the command line. Unfortunately I only have Windows, and cannot install new software.

```
type file1.txt file2.txt > out.txt
```

allows me to almost get what I want, but I don't want the 1st line of file2.txt to be included in out.txt.

I have noticed that `more` has the `+n` option to specify a starting line, but I haven't managed to combine these to get the result I want. I'm aware that this may not be possible in Windows, and I can always edit out.txt by hand to get rid of the line, but is there a simple way of doing it from the command line?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

```
more +2 file2.txt > temp
type temp file1.txt > out.txt
```

or you can use `copy`. See `copy /?` for more.

```
copy /b temp+file1.txt  out.txt
```

Comment: Of course! I would have preferred to have avoided the use of temporary files though. I tried to use parentheses, pipes and < to get it into one command, but couldn't get anywhere.

The `copy` command is much faster, but it puts a SUB character at the end. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I would add that if you want to concatenate ALL files you can do `copy /b *.txt combined.txt` without having to list the files individually.

Comment: more seemingly convert tab into spaces, pity!

Comment: is there any command to retrieve  original files from merged files?

Comment: @ghostdog74: I think it has to be `type file1.txt temp > out.txt` to actually append the second file, without a header to the first one

Answer (score 62):

I use this, and it works well for me:

`TYPE \\Server\Share\Folder\*.csv >> C:\Folder\ConcatenatedFile.csv`

Of course, before every run, you have to `DELETE C:\Folder\ConcatenatedFile.csv`

The only issue is that if all files have headers, then it will be repeated in all files.

Comment: When I enter a filename for the concatenated file, which means it's listed at the end of the files in the loaction (alphabetical order), then windows seems to concatenate twice! I ended up using a filename of 1filename.csv to not have the problem. I guess concatting into a different folder should work also...

Comment: If you use > instead of >>, you do not have to delete the file beforehand.  > redirects output and creates the file new every time.  >> redirects output and appends.

Comment: How does this skip the first line in file2, which the OP asked about?

Comment: It doesn't skip the first line in file2.  I missed that part of the question.

Comment: is there any command to retrieve original files from merged files?

Answer (score 23):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment on the recommendation to use `*.csv >> ConcatenatedFile.csv`, but I can add a warning:

If you create `ConcatenatedFile.csv` file in the same directory that you are using for concatenation it will be added to itself.

Comment: How does this skip the first line in file2, which the OP asked about?

Answer (score 6):

Use the FOR command to echo a file line by line, and with the 'skip' option to miss a number of starting lines...

```
FOR /F "skip=1" %i in (file2.txt) do @echo %i
```

You could redirect the output of a batch file, containing something like...

```
FOR /F %%i in (file1.txt) do @echo %%i
FOR /F "skip=1" %%i in (file2.txt) do @echo %%i
```

Note the double % when a FOR variable is used within a batch file.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to do this:

```
(type file1.txt && more +1 file2.txt) > out.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

I would put this in a comment to ghostdog74, except my rep is too low, so here goes.

`more +2 file2.txt > temp`

This code will actually ignore rows 1 and 2 of the file.  OP wants to keep all rows from the first file (to maintain the header row), and then exclude the first row (presumably the same header row) on the second file, so to exclude only the header row OP should use `more +1`.

`type temp file1.txt > out.txt`

It is unclear what order results from this code.  Is `temp` appended to `file1.txt` (as desired), or is `file1.txt` appended to `temp` (undesired as the header row would be buried in the middle of the resulting file).

In addition, these operations take a REALLY LONG TIME with large files (e.g. 300MB)

Answer (score 3):

In powershell:

```
Get-Content file1.txt | Out-File out.txt
Get-Content file2.txt | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File -Append out.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you said that you couldn't install any software, but I'm not sure how tight that restriction is. Anyway, I had the same issue (trying to concatenate two files with presumably the same headers) and I thought I'd provide an alternative answer for others who arrive at this page, since it worked just great for me.

After trying a whole bunch of commands in windows and being severely frustrated, and also trying all sorts of graphical editors that promised to be able to open large files, but then couldn't, I finally got back to my Linux roots and opened my Cygwin prompt. Two commands:

```
cp file1.csv out.csv
tail -n+2 file2.csv >> out.csv
```

For `file1.csv` 800MB and `file2.csv` 400MB, those two commands took under 5 seconds on my machine. In a Cygwin prompt, no less. I thought Linux commands were supposed to be slow in Cygwin but that approach took far less effort and was way easier than any windows approach I could find.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply try this

```
type file2.txt >> file1.txt
```

It will append the content of file2.txt at the end of file1.txt

If you need original file1.txt, take a backup beforehand. Or you can do this

```
type file1.txt > out.txt
type file2.txt >> out.txt
```

If you want to have a line break at the end of the first file, you can try the following command before appending.

```
type file1.txt > out.txt
printf "\n" >> out.txt
type file2.txt >> out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The help for `copy` explains that wildcards can be used to concatenate multiple files into one.

For example, to copy all .txt files in the current folder that start with "abc" into a single file named xyz.txt:

```
copy abc*.txt xyz.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, check out the FORFILES command.  You'll need to rework my example below to append the original file while leaving that out of the mask or you'll lose the column headers.  If you can arrange to have the column headers on the second line of the first file coming back from "*.csv", you'll be good anyway.  Like, put it in the root directory over the subdirectories where the real .csv files are.

Be careful with the output path because it seems like the command likes to do a 'cd' to the file path parent directory before running the 'cmd'.  So something like .\All.NotCSV will put one of those in each folder containing a .csv file and you'll be right back where you started.  You are better off hardwiring the output file path.

```
forfiles /S /M *.csv /C "cmd /C more +1 @path >> ..\All.NotCSV"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
more +2 file1.txt > type > out.txt && type file2.txt > out.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

This takes `Test.txt` with headers and appends `Test1.txt` and `Test2.txt` and writes results to `Testresult.txt` file after stripping headers from second and third files respectively:

```
type C:\Test.txt > C:\Testresult.txt && more +1 C:\Test1.txt >> C:\Testresult.txt && more +1 C:\Test2.txt >> C:\Testresult.txt
```