# R: how to rbind two huge data-frames without running out of memory

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, data.table, sqldf

I have two data-frames `df1` and `df2` that each have around 10 million rows and 4 columns. I read them into R using RODBC/sqlQuery with no problems, but when I try to `rbind` them, I get that most dreaded of R error messages: `cannot allocate memory`. There have got to be more efficient ways to do an `rbind` more efficiently -- anyone have their favorite tricks on this they want to share? For instance I found this example in the doc for `sqldf`:

```
# rbind
a7r <- rbind(a5r, a6r)
a7s <- sqldf("select * from a5s union all select * from a6s")
```

Is that the best/recommended way to do it?

***UPDATE***
I got it to work using the crucial `dbname = tempfile()` argument in the `sqldf` call above, as JD Long suggests in his answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r)

Comment: Good idea -- how do I do that -- you mean using something like `memory.limit(size = 4000)` ?

Comment: No. BTW, that works only in Windows. See my answer below.

Comment: You could always save them using `write.csv` and combine the data using the shell. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477271/concatenate-text-files-with-windows-command-line-dropping-leading-lines

Comment: Creating `sqldf`-based versions of functions like `rbind` sounds like a fun homework challenge for someone.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Rather than reading them into R at the beginning and then combining them you could have SQLite read them and combine them before sending them to R. That way the files are never individually loaded into R.

```
# create two sample files
DF1 <- data.frame(A = 1:2, B = 2:3)
write.table(DF1, "data1.dat", sep = ",", quote = FALSE)
rm(DF1)

DF2 <- data.frame(A = 10:11, B = 12:13)
write.table(DF2, "data2.dat", sep = ",", quote = FALSE)
rm(DF2)

# now we do the real work
library(sqldf)

data1 <- file("data1.dat")
data2 <- file("data2.dat")

sqldf(c("select * from data1", 
 "insert into data1 select * from data2", 
 "select * from data1"), 
 dbname = tempfile())
```

This gives:

```
>  sqldf(c("select * from data1", "insert into data1 select * from data2", "select * from data1"), dbname = tempfile())
   A  B
1  1  2
2  2  3
3 10 12
4 11 13
```

This shorter version also works if row order is unimportant:

```
sqldf("select * from data1 union select * from data2", dbname = tempfile())
```

See the sqldf home page http://sqldf.googlecode.com and `?sqldf` for more info.  Pay particular attention to the file format arguments since they are close but not identical to `read.table`.  Here we have used the defaults so it was less of an issue.

Comment: Neat approach... SQL is definitely capable of chewing something that big!

Comment: Very useful, thanks @Gabor... I have the data in an actual SQL database, and reading the entire thing with one query was hosing my memory, which is why I had to read each half into R first using `RODBC/sqlQuery` (don't ask me why it choked on the whole thing but did not choke when I read each half). But I agree if my original data is in two flat files, yours is the best way to read them in, and avoid having the two parts in R memory.

Answer (score 22):

Notice the `data.table` R package for efficient operations on objects with over several million records.

Version 1.8.2 of that package offers the `rbindlist` function through which you can achieve what you want very efficiently. Thus instead of `rbind(a5r, a6r)` you can:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(a5r, a6r))
```

Comment: Can you do this without loading the dataset into memory first?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a `data.frame` of desired size, hence import your data using subscripts.

```
dtf <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, 10, 10))
dtf1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:50, 5, 10, byrow=TRUE))
dtf2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(51:100, 5, 10, byrow=TRUE))
dtf[1:5, ] <- dtf1
dtf[6:10, ] <- dtf2
```

I guess that `rbind` grows object without pre-allocating its dimensions... I'm not positively sure, this is only a guess. I'll comb down "The R Inferno" or "Data Manipulation with R" tonight. Maybe `merge` will do the trick...

**EDIT**

And you should bare in mind that (maybe) your system and/or R cannot cope with something that big. Try RevolutionR, maybe you'll manage to spare some time/resources.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, thanks. I will try it out. (I don't want to go beyond the free R though, so Revo is not an option for me)

Comment: interesting suggestion, but it uses far more memory than rbind.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness in this thread on the topic of union:ing large files, try using shell commands on the files to combine them. In windows that is "COPY" command with "/B" flag. Example:

```
system(command =
         paste0(
           c("cmd.exe /c COPY /Y"
             , '"file_1.csv" /B'
             , '+ "file_2.csv" /B'
             , '"resulting_file.csv" /B'
           ), collapse = " "
         )
)#system
```

Requires that files have no header, and same delimiter etc etc.
The speed and versatility of shell commands is sometimes a great benefit, so don't forget CLI-commands when mapping out dataflows.