# Rbinding two big datasets

Tags: r, merge, dataset, rbind

I got two quite big datasets (190MB and 157.4 MB), which I would like to merge into one big dataset. However, when I try to combine those datasets with rbind R gives me the following error: "cannot allocate vector of size 421.1 MB).

Since I'm quite new into R I would really appreciate your help. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: how much memory do you have? admittedly 421 is a little bigger than 190+157, but it's not uncommon for an operation to take a little bit of memory 'headroom'.

Comment: Refer Memory efficient alternative to rbind - in-place rbind https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093984/memory-efficient-alternative-to-rbind-in-place-rbind