# R: Out of memory approach to rbind large data.frames using MonetDBLite

Tags: r, sqldf, monetdblite

I would like to mimic the solution once given to this question:
[R: how to rbind two huge data-frames without running out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761073/r-how-to-rbind-two-huge-data-frames-without-running-out-of-memory), but using R::MonetDBLite rather than R::SQLite

I tried the following without success:

```
library(DBI)
library(MonetDB.R)
library(MonetDBLite)
library(sqldf)

m <- dbDriver("MonetDBLite")

invisible(
sqldf::sqldf("create table test_table as select * from data1 union select * from data2",
      dbname="test.monetdb",
      drv=m,
      verbose = TRUE)
)
```

Thanks for your help.

edit: the error I get

```
Error in drv == "" :
comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
Error in !dbPreExists : invalid argument type
Timing stopped at: 0 0 0
```

Session informations:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252
LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
LC_TIME=French_France.1252
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
other attached packages:
[1] sqldf_0.4-10      RSQLite_1.0.0     gsubfn_0.6-6      proto_0.3-10
MonetDBLite_0.2.2 DBI_0.4-1         MonetDB.R_1.0.1
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.0      codetools_0.2-14 digest_0.6.9     chron_2.3-47
tcltk_3.3.0
```

Comment: It'll be helpful if you can tell us why it isn't succeeding (any errors, expected output vs actual output, etc.).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ytk : I edited my question with the error message I got after running the code.

Comment: @Sotos : shall I copy the minimal reproducible example from the original question I mentionned ?

Comment: sqldf works with SQLite, H2, MySQL and PostgreSQL backends.  You are trying to use it with a database that is not in that list and even if it were the `drv` argument is not a connection.  Please take the time to read the sqldf package documentation before posting.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck : thanks for the answer. I have read about the backend issue (I am certainly limited in the understanding though) but I was confused by the mention of  "MonetDBLite::RMonetDBLite driver" to work with sqldf on this site: https://github.com/hannesmuehleisen/MonetDBLite/issues/24

Comment: That refers to a fork of sqldf and not the one on CRAN.