# Merging multiple files in java

Tags: java

I have an array of files that i want to merge. This is what I tried but it did not work.

```
 public static void joinf(File f1, File f2){

    try{

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);


        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2,true);

        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("File copied.");
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + " in the specified directory.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());            
    }
}


public void pro(File a,File[]b){
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){


        joinf(a,b[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: so what's the problem with the above code?

Comment: If you want to just solve the problem you can use
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477271/concatenate-text-files-with-windows-command-line-dropping-leading-lines
Or cat file1 file2 ... filen > concatenated_file

Comment: @awregan - he wants to do it in Java ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/) to do this. See my example:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class SourceCodeProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        IOCopier.joinFiles(new File("D:/d.txt"), new File[] {
                new File("D:/s1.txt"), new File("D:/s2.txt") });
    }
}

class IOCopier {
    public static void joinFiles(File destination, File[] sources)
            throws IOException {
        OutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = createAppendableStream(destination);
            for (File source : sources) {
                appendFile(output, source);
            }
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
        }
    }

    private static BufferedOutputStream createAppendableStream(File destination)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        return new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destination, true));
    }

    private static void appendFile(OutputStream output, File source)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));
            IOUtils.copy(input, output);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);
        }
    }
}
```

If you can't use IOUtils lib, then write your own implementation. Example:

```
class IOUtils {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 4;

    public static long copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
            throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        long count = 0;
        int n = 0;
        while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, n);
            count += n;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void closeQuietly(Closeable output) {
        try {
            if (output != null) {
                output.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't use this import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

Comment: Why you can't use it? This is very popular lib.

Comment: but it give me error on this   finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
        } what should i do?

Comment: please help me it's so important for me

Comment: What the problem do you have? For me everything works OK.

Comment: it's work but not correctly -it doesn't merge all file and it just merge  the first line of the files

Comment: Hmm... Strange. I've tested it and it works fine for me. Have you changed anything?

Comment: thank's i find the problem -the problem was belong to another method not your method thank's a lot

Answer (score 0):

In its current form, your `pro` method appends file `a` to each of the `b` files.  The reason is that your `joinf(a, b)` method appends file `a` to file `b`, not the other way around.

To fix it, this:

```
joinf(a,b[i]);
```

should be changed to this:

```
joinf(b[i], a);
```

or something like that.

---

FYI: there are various other problems in your code as written.  Please review them so that you can write better code next time ...

- Your joinf method could leak file descriptors in certain circumstances - resources should be closed (explicitly or implicitly) in a `finally`.
- Calling `System.exit()` in a library method like that makes it difficult to reuse.
- You are throwing away stack traces.  That will make debugging of a field-deployed copy of your app difficult.
- The strategy for dealing with IOException is wrong.  If you get an unexpected IOException there, something is seriously amiss.  Print and continue is a really bad idea.
- The names `pro` and `joinf` are poor choices.
- No javadocs

Comment: but i want to appends all b files into a file

Comment: Okay, go ahead. He just told you what is wrong.

Comment: @user1781384 - *"but i want to appends all b files into a file"* - I just explained *why* your program doesn't do that, and gave you a suggestion of how to fix it.  If you don't understand, please say what you don't understand.