# merging files in java

Tags: java, arrays, file, merge, append

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [merging file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673063/merging-file-in-java)

i have an array of files that i want to merge them in one file. I used this but this not work

```
public static void joinf(File f1, File f2){

    try{

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);


        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2,true);

        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("File copied.");
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + " in the specified directory.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());            
    }
}


public void pro(File a,File[]b){
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){


        joinf(a,b[i]);
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673063/merging-file-in-java

Comment: Please do not post [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14673063/335858) again.

Comment: because i didn't get the answer so i had to re share it

Comment: Your names are terrible. Which is the file to receive the concatenated output, a or b[i]? Which is the file to receive the concatenated output, f1 or f2? If you gave them meaningful names, at least one problem would become obvious to you. Always give your variables meaningful names.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
    joinf(b[i],a);
```

instead of

```
    joinf(a,b[i]);
```