# Combining all text files in a folder into a single file

Tags: java, file-io

How can I combine all txt files in a folder into a single file? A folder usually contains hundreds to thousands of txt files.

If this program were only to be run on windows machines I would just go with a batch file containing something like

`copy /b *.txt merged.txt`

But that is not the case, so I figured it might be easier to just write it in Java to complement everything else we have.

I have written something like this

```
// Retrieves a list of files from the specified folder with the filter applied
File[] files = Utils.filterFiles(downloadFolder + folder, ".*\\.txt");
try
{
  // savePath is the path of the output file
  FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(savePath);

  for (File file : files)
  {
      FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream(file);
      Integer b = null;
      while ((b = inFile.read()) != -1)
          outFile.write(b);
      inFile.close();
  }
  outFile.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it takes several minutes to combine thousands of files so it is not feasible.

Comment: You're reading one byte at a time...

Comment: oh, read() doesn't try to read as much as it can? That probably explains why it's so slow

Comment: No, it reads a single byte (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html), use the other read() methods that accept a `byte[]`.

Comment: @fge some machines are still running on java 6 but it should not be an issue.

Comment: Well, even Java 6 has `FileChannel`, you should take full advantage of that

Comment: Yes, I don't really want to have to do any of this file I/O myself if I don't have to.

Comment: @MxyL  I also want to do same kind of thing. Your code is helpfull for me. Can I know in `File[] files = Utils.filterFiles(downloadFolder + folder, ".*\\.txt");` what is `downloadFolder`  and  `folder` and  `".*\\.txt"`  ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of this

```
  Integer b = null;
  while ((b = inFile.read()) != -1)
      outFile.write(b);
```

Your OS is making a lot of IO calls. [`read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29) only reads one byte of data. Use the other [read methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) that accept a `byte[]`. You can then use that `byte[]` to write to your `OutputStream`. Similarly `write(int)` does an IO call writing a single byte. Change that too.

Of course, you can look into tools that do this for you, like Apache Commons IO or even the Java 7 NIO package.

Comment: I'll probably switch over to NIO after I figure out how to merge files myself. Thanks for pointing out the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use NIO, it is *much* easier than using inputstreams/outputstreams. Note: uses Guava's `Closer`, which means all resources are safely closed; even better would be to use Java 7 and try-with-resources.

```
final Closer closer = Closer.create();

final RandomAccessFile outFile;
final FileChannel outChannel;

try {
    outFile = closer.register(new RandomAccessFile(dstFile, "rw"));
    outChannel = closer.register(outFile.getChannel());
    for (final File file: filesToCopy)
        doWrite(outChannel, file);
} finally {
    closer.close();
}

// doWrite method

private static void doWrite(final WriteableByteChannel channel, final File file)
    throws IOException
{
    final Closer closer = Closer.create();

    final RandomAccessFile inFile;
    final FileChannel inChannel;

    try {
        inFile = closer.register(new RandomAccessFile(file, "r"));
        inChannel = closer.register(inFile.getChannel());
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), channel);
    } finally {
        closer.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) instead of writing bytes one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IoUtils to merge files,IoUtils.copy() method will help you for merging files.

This link may be useful [merging file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673063/merging-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way !

1. check for the OS

   System.getProperty("os.name")
2. Run the System Level command from Java.

   If windows

   ```
           copy /b *.txt merged.txt
   ```

   if Unix

   ```
           cat *.txt > merged.txt
   ```

   or whatever best System level command available.