# how to read the data from the files of a directory

Tags: java

```
    public class FIlesInAFolder {

        private static BufferedReader br;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            File folder = new File("C:/filesexamplefolder");
            FileReader fr = null;

            if (folder.isDirectory()) {
                for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
                    if (fileEntry.isFile()) {
                        try {
                            fr = new FileReader(folder.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + fileEntry.getName());
                            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
System.out.println(""+br.readLine());
                        }
                        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        finally {
                            br.close();
                            fr.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

how to print the first word from first file of a directory and the second word from second file and third word from a third file of the same directory.

```
i am able to open directory and print the line from each file of the directory,
but tell me how to print the first word from first file and second word from second file and so on . .
```

Comment: It's not easy to read data from a ditectory...

Comment: create different streams for each file

Comment: Please, revise following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673063/merging-file-in-java

Comment: You have new FileReader(folder.getAbsolutePath()+"\\"+fileEntry.getName()), where new FIleReader(fileEntry) will do

Comment: also read the body of the message completely

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below will read first word from first file, second word from second file, ... nth word from nth file. You'll likely want to do some additional work to improve the codes stability.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class SOAnswer {

    private static void printFirst(File file, int offset) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line = null;
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
            String[] split = line.split(" ");
            if(split.length >= offset) {
                String targetWord = split[offset];
            } 
            // we do not care if files are read that do not match your requirements, or 
            // for reading complete files as you only care for the first word
            break;
        }

        br.close();
        fr.close(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
         File folder = new File(args[0]);
         if(folder.isDirectory()) {
             int offset = 0;
             for(File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
                 if(fileEntry.isFile()) {
                     printFirst(fileEntry, offset++); // handle exceptions if you wish
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```