# Regarding four byte array needs to be write to a new File

Tags: java

```
List<byte[]> A has four byte[] values
```

When I run a for each loop for the array A and write to a File using writeByteArrayToFile(File,byte[],true);

It is just overwriting and the last byte[] value is only written in file?

I need to write all the byte[]???

Comment: And what have you try so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging multiple files in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673063/merging-multiple-files-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File A = new File("A");
        File B = new File("B");
        File C = new File("C");
        File D = new File("D");

        File E = new File("E");
        mergeFiles(E, A, B, C, D);
}

static void mergeFiles(File destination, File... files) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
    int count;
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination)) {
        for (File file : files) {
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                while ((count = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anton I almost got it thank you so much @Anton but I have a prob in that while loop first time when File A comes in it is becoming false..only three Files B,C,D gets write .. can you find the prob???

Comment: @SethuRamalingam method `read()` returns the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of the file has been reached.

Comment: thank you..but I have tried what happens is the fourth File D is only getting written in File E..but I need all four files..kindly help me sir..

Comment: write method overwrites in the for loop during each iteration so only the last file is getting written to File E???

Comment: File A has values written in it
File B has values written in it
File C has values written in it
File D has values written in it

File E = new File(“E”);
E = mergeFiles(E,A,B,C,D);

Private File mergeFiles(File E,File... files) throws IOException{
byte[] buffer = new byte[300000];
int count;
try(FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(E)){
for(File file : files){
try(FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)){
while((count=fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
fileOutputStream.write(buffer,0,count);
}
}
}
}
return E;
}

Comment: @SethuRamalingam are you sure that you save changes in your files. This code absolutely correct. I create four files A,B,C,D with content and at result had E file with content of A,B,C,D files. If you want to append content of A,B,C,D files to already exist file E you have to use `new FileOutputStream(E, true)` constructor.

Comment: Thank you, actually that four File values has been formed using byte array to File conversion using FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file,byteArray); so is there some prob with that ..if so how to save those files in code???

Comment: I also tried to merge the four byte[]to a single byte[] and then write to a File but still only the fourth byte[] is written in the File E..I couldn’t find the solution..

Comment: still only the fourth File is getting displayed in File E.. but I need 4 pages as output in File E i.e) File A in page 1, File B in page 2, File C in page 3, File D in page 4??kindly help me

Comment: the code we are trying what it does is copying ..ex : if you have two Files A and B then this code copies the File B to A..so in our case in the for loop each time it writes File A to E then next time File B to E and so on..so the output is File D in File E is got..tats the problem for me..kindly help me resolve ASAP

Comment: @SethuRamalingam Can you create new question and paste your code there. I need your fully code listing to review it and try to help. Especially interested how you call `mergeFile()` method. May be you use external loop or something else.

Comment: Okay @Anton..I will add a new question and let u know