# How to use parallel computing in converting Raster to txt file

Tags: r, parallel-processing, raster

I have a huge raster (> 20 GB) and trying to convert it to one txt file. Is there a way to do that in parallel R computing? I couldn't load RAM to the memory as it is quite bit.

My computer has 8 cores and 16 Gb of RAM

best

Comment: What is a raster and what exactly does 'convert it to one txt file' mean?

Comment: A raster is a spatial data structure that divides a region of any shape into rectangles. Think of it as a grid with many cells. 'convert it to one txt file' means that the OP wants to change the file format such as converting a file from GeoTIFF to ASCII

Answer (score 0):

Divide your raster in 2 rasters, in the most convenient way to recombine them later (a horizontal division). Then create 2 .txt files using the same command on 2 different instances of R. You can try to recombine them afterwards using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477271/concatenate-text-files-with-windows-command-line-dropping-leading-lines) if you use Windows.

You can divide your original rasters in 8 and do the same but I guess it would be tedious (although likely faster).