# How can I concat files with Ant if source files is changed?

Tags: ant

How can I concat files with Ant if source files is changed?

I create such code but it is very complex to do such simple thing - want to do in more simple way - can I do it?

```
<target name="check.src/web_site/seo/frontend/base/crud/yaml/keyword/list/static/list.js">
    <uptodate property="dirty.src/web_site/seo/frontend/base/crud/yaml/keyword/list/static/list.js"
        targetfile="src/web_site/seo/frontend/base/crud/yaml/keyword/list/static/list.js">
        <srcfiles file="src/web_site/seo/frontend/base/crud/yaml/base/list/static/list.js"></srcfiles>
        <srcfiles file="src/web_site/seo/frontend/base/crud/yaml/keyword/list/js/list.js"></srcfiles>
    </uptodate>
    <echo message="result: ${dirty.src/web_site/seo/frontend/base/crud/yaml/keyword/list/static/list.js}"/>
</target>

<target name="src/web_site/seo/frontend/base/crud/yaml/keyword/list/static/list.js"
    depends="check.src/web_site/seo/frontend/base/crud/yaml/keyword/list/static/list.js"
    unless="dirty.src/web_site/seo/frontend/base/crud/yaml/keyword/list/static/list.js">
    <echo message="concat"></echo>
    <concat destfile="src/web_site/seo/frontend/base/crud/yaml/keyword/list/static/list.js"
        fixlastline="true" >
        <fileset file="src/web_site/seo/frontend/base/crud/yaml/base/list/static/list.js"></fileset>
        <fileset file="src/web_site/seo/frontend/base/crud/yaml/keyword/list/js/list.js"></fileset>
    </concat>
</target>
```

Comment: Are you ok to run os commands to combine files as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477271/concatenate-text-files-with-windows-command-line-dropping-leading-lines)?

Answer (score 0):

Since ant 1.8.2, you can use `overwrite` property of the [concat](http://ant.apache.or/manual/Tasks/concat.html) task for that purpose.

Before version 1.8.2, you may use the `force` property instead.