# Copy text files into one file including filenames

Tags: windows, text, cmd

From the Windows command prompt it's possible to collect all text files into one file using

```
copy *.txt all_text_files.txt
```

Is it possible to add the name of each file added in front of the file in question? In my example I have two text files a & b.

a.txt consists of one line:

```
Cheese
```

b.txt also consists of one line:

```
Monkeys
```

The new file would be:

```
a.txt
Cheese
b.txt
Monkeys
```

Comment: See this answer. I think its relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2477341/445695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type *.txt >allfiles.out 2>&1
ren allfiles.out allfiles.txt
```

`type` types all matching files. The file contents goes to STDOUT, the filenames are printed to STDERR. So just redirect both to the new file. Choose a different extension to avoid recursive handling.

Answer (score 2):

If you write it directly in the command line, this should work. If you want to make a script I believe you need to put double `%`

```
for %f in (*.txt) do (
    echo "%f"
    type "%f"
) > all_text_files.txt
```

Comment: Not sure if that works with files with spaces in the name

Comment: It doesn't, but you just need to add `"`. I edited my answer.